# Unix redirecting grep command to a file

Tags: unix, grep, command

For an assignment I have to do the following: 'Grab all the lines beginning with an uppercase letter, that only contain alphabets (upper or lowercase) in "test1.txt". Redirect the output of this command to be appended to the existing "output2.txt".'

I tried using

```
grep ^[A-Z]*[a-z] > test1.txt >> output2.txt
```

but it gives me an error saying "Ambiguous output redirect". I'm still learning how to use Unix so I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid doing the assignment, I'll give a simple example of how the output redirects work using `cat`. You can translate to `grep`.

```
$ # Print file to standard output
$ cat test1.txt
abc
Abc
9B
$ # Print to another file, overwriting existing file
$ cat test1.txt > output2.txt
$ cat output2.txt
abc
Abc
9B
$ # Print to another file, appending to existing file
$ cat test1.txt >> output2.txt
$ cat output2.txt
abc
Abc
9B
abc
Abc
9B
```

Answer (score 0):

The command should be like this:

```
egrep "^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*$"  test1.txt > output2.txt
```

You should use `egrep` as you want to use regex. Then you search for 1st symbol to be upper case char, then the next to be only chars so the regex should be like this. Then yoy should use `test1.txt` as input file (you set it as redirect from STDOUT) and then you do not need to append because entire command will output all the strings at once